# How to have index of summation equal to all $n$-tuples $\left(b_i\right)_{i\le n}$ with $\sum ib_i = n$ and $b_j$ fixed?

Tags: function-construction, summation, tuples

Let $T_n$ denote the set of $n$-tuples $\left(b_1, \ldots, b_n \right)$ of non-negative integers such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}ib_i=n.$$ I am trying to simplify the sum (whose indicies depend solely on $n, j$, and $k$)

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\underset{b_{j}=k}{\left(b_{i}\right)_{i\le n}\in T_{n}}}\frac{n\left(n-1\right)\cdots\left(n-\sum_{i\le n}b_{i}+2\right)}{\prod_{l\le n}\left(b_l !\right)}.
\end{align*}

where one of the components (component $b_j$) is equal to some number $k$ specified in advance.

> How can I sum over all tuples in $T_n$ such that the $j$th component is fixed?

I am seeking a symbolic solution for general $n, k$, and $j$. In many cases, the sum will be zero (e.g., the largest $b_n$ can be is $1$ due to the weighted sum constraint on $T_n$.

**Example**
For example, if $n=5$ and the second component is fixed to be $1$ ($b_2 = 1)$, then the sum above has two terms corresponding to the vectors $(3,1,0,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1,0, 0)$.

Comment: If the smallest $b_i$ can be is 1, then isn't $\sum_{i=1}^n i b_i$ always greater than $n$?

Comment: $b_i$ can be $0$.

Comment: Sorry.  Don't know why I read "non-negative" as "positive".  Need more coffee this morning.

Comment: What values of $n$ are you considering?  Small integers?  Large integers?  A symbolic solution for general $n$ and $k$?

Comment: @JimB The latter, but I would settle for something that will allow me to plug in values of $n$ and $k$.

Comment: Please post an example about `How can I sum over all tuples in Tn such that the jth component is fixed?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I've interpreted everything correctly, I have just brute-forced it as

```
sumB[{pos_, val_}, n_] /; pos <= n := Module[{bList},
  bList = Solve[n == Sum[i b[i] /. b[pos] -> val, {i, 1, n}], Delete[Array[b, n], pos], NonNegativeIntegers];
  If[bList != {}, bList = Array[b, n] /. bList /. b[pos] -> val];
  Sum[n!/(n - Total[bees] + 1)! 1/Times @@ Factorial[bees], {bees, bList}]
 ]
```

The first line generates the $n$-tuples $b_i$ satisfying $\sum_iib_i=n$ subject to $b_{\textrm{pos}}=\textrm{val}$. The second line then performs the sum.

---

`NonNegativeIntegers` was introduced in Version 12.  Before that, one can use `FrobeniusSolve` and `Select` the relevant lists:

```
sumB[{pos_, val_}, n_] /; pos <= n := Module[{bList},
  bList = Select[FrobeniusSolve[Range[n], n], #[[pos]] == val &];
  Sum[n!/(n - Total[bees] + 1)! 1/Times @@ Factorial[bees], {bees, bList}]
]
```

Comment: @TheSubstitute See if this does what you expect.

Comment: I haven't been able to obtain an output when I evaluate that.

Comment: @TheSubstitute. What version are you using? It might be the NonNegativeIntegers part, which was introduced in version 12.  I've updated the code with something that should work pre-Version 12.

Comment: +1 Trying a few values of `val` and for specific pairs of `n` and `pos` and then plugging in the results of 'sumB` into oeis.org finds "the number of Dyck paths of semilength n having `val` ascents of length `pos`": sequence A102402 when `pos = 2`.

Comment: @march The second code is not defined at 'sumB[{2, 2}, 5]' whereas the first code gives the correct answer of 10.

Comment: @TheSubstitute I recently (ten minutes ago?) fixed an error in the code. `sumB[{2, 2}, 5]` works just fine and returns `10` for both bits of code above. And note that I converted your $n(n-1)\cdots$ into the corresponding expression in terms of factorials, which is why I add 1 instead of 2 in that expression (i.e., $n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+2)=n!/(n-k+1)!$).

Comment: @march Thank you. Is there a way to apply the code when I plug in arbitrary $j, k, n$? E.g., ```sumB[{2, 1}, n]``` should equal ${n \choose 2}$.

Comment: @TheSubstitute My code absolutely requires a value for `n`, and I don't see a way of doing this that will evaluate the sum symbolically, Mathematica doesn't have a lot of built-in symbolic summing stuff. You'd likely have to write your own code that does symbolic summation of some sort or another, and I imagine that would be equivalent with just proving it by hand.

Comment: @Substitute Also, if it's the case that `sumB[{2, 1}, n]` should be n-choose-2, then my code is wrong. Perhaps you can sort through what I've done and determine why! I'm note *entirely* sure that I've understood your original problem, and that might be the issue.

Comment: @march Sorry, the n-choose-2 statement on my end was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

- `T[n]` is `FrobeniusSolve[Range[n], n]`.
- But I still don't understand the meaning of

> How can I sum over all tuples in Tn such that the jth component is fixed?

so the code as below sum all the `T[n]` for fixed `n`.

```
Clear[T, n];
T[n_] := FrobeniusSolve[Range[n], n];
n = 8;
Product[m, {m, n, n - Plus @@ #+2, -1}]/Times @@ (#!) & /@ T[n] // Total
```

Comment: I included an example to clarify. I want to be able to fix one of the entries in the vector (such as setting the 3rd entry equal to 2) and then sum over all of the vectors with this constraint.

Comment: Your code gives the Catalan numbers.

Comment: @JimB  Thanks!  Your comment enlightening me!